# Compile Library for local use with Latex

Tags: latex

I'm have a Latex template that still uses scrpage2. Since this library has been marked as outdated Miktex and Texlive both report `File 'scrpage2.sty' not found.` The recommendation is, to simply replace it with scrlayer-scrpage but if I do that, other things in the template, which is quite elaborate, break. My Idea was, to download the library from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrpage2, compile it and simply change the imports in the template to the locally compiled scrpage2.sty. Unfortunately the package only contains `scrlettr.ins` which in turn, when i run `latex scrlettr.ins` builds `scrlettr.cls` but not `scrpage2.sty`.

How do I get `scrpage2.sty` so I can use it locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preface:

Using an old package version with a newer latex distribution can lead to all kinds of problems. Modifications to the kernel/class/other packages might be incompatible. My recommendation would be:

1. Solve the problems with `scrlayer-scrpage`  and your template instead
2. If these problems can't be solved, use an older version of texlive which still has the package. You can find links to historic releases here: https://www.tug.org/historic/

---

To answer the actual question:

run `tex scrpage2-obsolete.dtx` to extract the .sty file